# Questions about a tutorial regarding interactive heatmaps with plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, plotly

i recently started playing with `ggplot2`, and also with `plotly`. When I found a very interesting tutorial in `plotly`'s web page:

**https://plot.ly/ggplot2/ggdendro-dendrograms/**

concerning the creation of interactive heatmap, I have some very specific questions about some parts of the code

1) The first question that i'm a bit confused is :

I see in the beginning a first scaling of data:

```
x <- as.matrix(scale(mtcars))
```

and then, below, in the part # heatmap:

```
xx <- scale(mtcars)[col.ord, row.ord]
```

So, why a second scaling is used with the objects `col.ord` and `row.ord`? Or it has a different purpose from the original scaling of the data?
Moreover, if I use for instance a different kind of data, such as microarray datasets, which are already normalized--if i would like to scale again my data, I should use only the second function of scaling? That is something similar to:

```
xx <- scale(mtcars)[col.ord, row.ord]
```

2) By which function or argument:

i) can I adjust the column names to look more clear ?

ii) Change the color palette to have a different range of colors ??

Comment: The author could have equivalently written `xx <- x[col.ord, row.ord]`. Note that `[col.ord, row.ord]` is just reordering the columns and rows of the scaled object. The scalings performed in the two sections you highlight are identical. Your other questions aren't very specific. You should demonstrate what you've tried, and exactly what your problems are.

Comment: Dear jbaums, thank you for your answer !! so, i was in first part confused that x <- as.matrix(scale(mtcars)) is different from just xx <- scale(mtcars) !! Regarding my second question, im just wondering which aesthetics or arguments of ggplot function can i use to improve the visualization of the column names-in order to look more clear-- & also if i could use a different color palette ?